# Read IP (UDP) data and save to audio file format

Tags: c#

I am read to IP data and store to notepad(.txt file format) file,after save this stored notepad data convert to audio(.Wav) five format using "Naudio" library(Namespace) in c#.

Problem : audio file voice(clarity) not proper.

```
UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(8081);
IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("x.x.x.x"), listenPort);

while (true)
{
      byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
      string path = "E:\\Audio\\8081.txt";
      using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
      {
         writer.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length));
         writer.Close();
      }
      WaveFormat waveFormat = WaveFormat.CreateMuLawFormat(8000, 1);
      using (WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter("C:\\8081.Wav",waveFormat))
     {
       byte[] bytes1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(File.ReadAllText("E:\\Audio\\8081.txt"));
       writer.WriteData(bytes1, 0, bytes1.Length);
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your question but react at storing audio as text. Audio is typically streamed bits while text is... text. When working with a binary stream it is crucial that every bit is correct and in the right order. When working with text some things change, like how to format line endings or special chäråctêrs. They are usually *not* compatible.

Comment: i get audio data from IP and try to save in audio file format, but audio quality not good.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII is a 7-bit encoding. If you bytes's value is greater then 127, it might be modified by encoder/decoder. This means that if you do for instance:

```
var bytes1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));
```

your **bytes1** array values might be different from those of **bytes**.

The most simple way around this problem would be to save your data in a binary format, without converting it into a text.

If you absolutely need text conversion, use

```
Convert.ToBase64String / Convert.FromBase64String
```

Comment: Can you give me example,

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx  - they write string to a file by converting it into a byte array. It is even easier for you since you start with a byte array.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, i have store data with binary writer but same issue exits

Comment: Did you check if the data you read from the file is the same as you've written?